# Rails - ckeditor orm failed to install correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

So i made a bit of a mistake when trying to add ckeditor to my Rails project last night.
I was following a tutorial and it came to a point in the installation of this gem where it told me to input the following command:

```
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave
```

except i misspelled 'record'
I've looked everywhere i can think and i cant seem to fix this, rails d ... doesnt work gem uninstall doesnt fix it either, and i can't see any related files in my db folder, or anywhere else that i know to look at.

heres the first bit of the error i keep seeing:

```
/home/naazarik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- ckeditor/orm/active_recort (LoadError)
    from /home/naazarik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
```

notice the misspelled active_recort? 
anyways does anyone have any idea how to either fix this, or remove this from my project?

Thanks!

Comment: May you add console output for generator call? And your `config/initializers/ckeditor.rb` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor installer should generate `config/initializers/ckeditor.rb` file that in your case will have following line: `require 'ckeditor/orm/active_recort'`, which you can update to say `active_record` instead

However, ActiveRecord integration requires a few more files to be generated (and these files were not generated due to a misspelling). Because of that I believe the best way to fix the problem is just to remove the initializer file entirely and run the `rails generate ckeditor:install` command again.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Supercatfishpro can you mark my answer as accepted? So that other people who see this question on the list know it's already solved. Glad I could help! :)